# What's the meaning of "belong at"?

Tags: meaning

I've seen **belong+to** many times but I've read recently **belong at** in text below:

> Someone like me did not belong at Cambridge.

Could you please tell me what the meaning of "belong at" is?

The full text is here:

> A FEW WEEKS AFTER CHRISTMAS, the University of Cambridge wrote to Dr.
>   Kerry, rejecting my application. “The competition was very steep,” Dr.
>   Kerry told me when I visited his office.
>   I thanked him and stood to go.
>   “One moment,” he said. “Cambridge instructed me to write if I felt there
>   were any gross injustices.”
>   I didn’t understand, so he repeated himself. “I could only help one
>   student,” he said. “They have offered you a place, if you want it.”
>   It seemed impossible that I would really be allowed to go. Then I realized
>   that I would need a passport, and that without a real birth certificate, I was
>   unlikely to get one. **Someone like me did not belong at Cambridge**. It was
>   as if the universe understood this and was trying to prevent the blasphemy
>   of my going.

Comment: to belong at a place (here, a university) means: to be at a place that is the right place for you. Usually, without at: I really belong here or there. BUT: to be at university or school, so it's OK here to say: belong at Cambridge. That woman's story is SO amazing. to belong at school, at university, at a place of work, at a location. But a geographical place:  in a city or town or country.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Belong X* can mean "to be a member or part of X" but it can also mean "harmonizes with existing people/things" - usually based on appearance or other observable attribute.

With the second meaning, the X in "belong X" might be a place, and *at* or other spatial preposition would be used.

> These files don't look like they belong in this box (files are different type)
>
> This car doesn't belong at the scrapyard, it still works.

Comment: Well said. And we all belong in the loony bin. :)